# how to keep the old structure in ckeditor

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

I use CKEditor to create/edit rich text. And I have a template which contains a link looks like a button in mail. but when I edit this template via rich text editor, the button view of button disappear in mail.

```php
$template = "<p>&nbsp;</p><p>Thank u and bla bla</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>you can click this link;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><a href='". route('test') ."' class='test-button'>View</a><p>&nbsp;</p><p><a href='asdfg' target='_blank' class='test-link'><b>This</b></a>is a link </p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>See you later</p>"
```

button in mail(before edit)
[image]

after edit
[image]

how to keep this button view in email?

Comment: You need to include the CSS for the test-button class

Comment: I have it in my mail blade. the problem is that a tag which has test-button class disappear and an ordinary a tag replace it